# Append text to existing line in a file

Tags: java

I'm working on a school project right now, and I amseriously struggling trying to append text to an existing line in my .txt file. 
What I would like to see is that if a "show name" matches with one in the .txt file the next line which contains [HOST] a username will be added. I've so far created this method:

```
    public void joinAShow(String username, String showName) throws IOException{
    keepGoing = true;
    keepGoing2 = true;
    while((line = bufferedReader2.readLine()) != null && keepGoing){
        if(line.equals(showTitle)){
            while((line = bufferedReader2.readLine()) != null && keepGoing2){
                if(line.contains("[HOST]")){
                    line += ", " + username;
                }
            }
        }
        keepGoing = false;
        keepGoing2 = false;
    }
}
```

At this point I'm quite certain I can't do it because I'm using a reader of some sort, and not a writer, but I wouldn't know how to come around this. I'm quite stuck and has been for a time at this point. I hope some clever minds can tell an quite easy way to come around this.
My data set looks like the following:

```
Stream1
Review
Stream
2020-10-10 10:00
90
0.0
admin[HOST]
Stream2
Review
Stream
2020-10-10 10:00
90
0.0
admin[HOST]
Stream3
Review
Stream
2020-10-10 10:00
90
0.0
admin[HOST]
```

I really hope some one can help. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Here you are not writing it back to the existing .txt file. It is a 3 step process. First, you need to read an existing .txt file, find a specific line where you want to append data and write back it to the file

Comment: @NitinBisht so if I read the file into a list of some sort, "edit" the line and then rewrite the file?

Comment: Yes, Although there are various ways to solve a problem. I think we can go with this approach in your case as your text file is also not very large so you can go this way. If you want then I can make a running short prototype then you can edit it as per your business logic.

Comment: @NitinBisht I'd be more than happy if you'd do that for me, I feel kind of blind on this. I can't seem to come further. So I'd very much appreciate your prototype of a solution :)

Comment: Hold on I am adding an answer for this.

Comment: I have added an answer. Kindly check and let me know if it works.

Comment: I'll test it right away, coming back soon. Thanks a lot!

Comment: This did indeed work, thanks a lot! May you have a great day!

Comment: Glad I could help you thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.nio.charset.StandardCharsets;
import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.nio.file.Path;
import java.nio.file.Paths;
import java.util.List;

public class Demo {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

        // Update line number 7 and append Test to it
        updateLine(7, "Test");
    }

    public static void updateLine(int lineNumber, String data) throws IOException {
        // Path of file
        Path path = Paths.get("etc/demo.txt");
        // Read all lines
        List<String> lines = Files.readAllLines(path, StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
        // Update line 7 - Replace admin HOST with admin HOST Test
        lines.set(lineNumber - 1, lines.get(lineNumber - 1) + " " + data);
        // Write back to the file
        Files.write(path, lines, StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
    }
}
```

**Before demo.txt file:**

[image]

**After demo.txt file:**

[image]

**Explanation:**

1. Reading data line by line from file `demo.txt` file.
2. Updated `Line 7` and replace `admin HOST` with `admin HOST Test`.
3. Write data back to the file.

**Note:** This is an example that will help you to update code as per your requirement.